# php eclipse mars update - xdebug - windows - no appropriate file located

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I've just made an update to eclipse mars and all my project were left as they were. everything works fine except xdebug;

I am on windows7 64b; I'm making debug on remote server; I have all configs fine on server:

```
xdebug.remote_enable 1
xdebug.remote_host "mylocalip"
xdebug.idekey XDEBUG_ECLIPSE_DBG
xdebug.remote_autostart 0
```

I've also enabled the xdebug log. From there I've found out IDE & xdebug are communicating fine:

```
xdebug.remote_log /var/www/html/xdebug.log

I: Connecting to configured address/port: .....:9000. 
I: Connected to client. :-)
```

I've tried all combinations of `Path Mapping` in `PHP -> Debug -> Debggers -> PHP Server` (because I have sources on local disk and I sync them to server on build).

Result:

> No appropriate file located or no file selected. Debug Terminated

The only issue I can see is that Eclipse Mars is having an issue with xdebug configs or smth.

**Solution Update:**

You also get error this if you are missing project include path under your project settings: `PHP Include Path > Source.`

Comment: You also get error this if you are missing project include path under your project settings: PHP Include Path > Source.  ; solution from http://w3facility.org/question/please-help-with-eclipseide-message-no-appropriate-file-located-or-no-file-selected-debug-terminated/#answer-9239474